# Short story about (three?) waves of plague

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I can't remember when I read this short story, it is probably in the 60s or 70s. I don't even remember it as particularly good but it is apposite for our present situation. It's a long time ago so my memory is vague and very likely faulty.

Two men are conversing, possibly in a vehicle. Let's call them A and B. There have been waves of plague and each one kills off a significant proportion of the population but leaves the remainder stronger* and A is able to feel some kind of furniture flexing under his grip as a result of his increased strength. During conversation B reveals that he is responsible for the plagues and intends to release just one more. A reflects on a female who is dear to him and is unlikely to survive the last wave so he kills B.

*I don't recall how the plague makes the survivors stronger; possibly bad science.

Comment: I've read this. Does the plague do something to the victim's skin, making it more resilient as if impregnated with silicone? I seem to remember one of the characters holding aloft a vial of white powder which he's going to sprinkle on the victims' food. They will have to change their metabolism in order to digest it. Some will succeed and some won't; the latter will die, while the former will incorporate elements from the powder into their bodies, becoming stronger. The science wasn't very plausible, but the story had quite an emotional effect on me. Possibly in a "Star SF" anthology?

Comment: @PhilvanKleur No, that doesn't ring any bells at all. It was a long time ago but I think they are different stories.